# How to call a factory method dynamically coming from variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory, dynamic-variables

I have a service which will return the name of factory. I already injected all the factories into controller. I need to use the variable to call the method inside that factory. I know i can use

```
if(var == 'factoryname') {
     factoryname.method()
}
```

but i don't want those if conditions because i have number of factories. Is there any way to call a method inside that factory like in java script 

`window[var]`

Comment: That is some bizarre architecture, I can't imagine that will be good, maintainable etc.

Comment: Why would you inject all the factories if you only might use some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider storing all of your factories on an object:

```
var factories = {
  factoryA: { method: function() {} },
  factoryB: { method: function() {} },
};

var factory = 'factoryA';

factories[factory].method();
```